# Storybook error Unexpected default export without title: {"includeStories":[],"parameters":{"docs":{}}}

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am following along to the [Learn Storybook](https://www.learnstorybook.com/design-systems-for-developers/react/en/document/) official tutorial

I am getting the error `Unexpected default export without title: {"includeStories":[],"parameters":{"docs":{}}}`.

I only have one story in a CreditCard.stories.mdx file in the stories directory:

```
import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
import { withKnobs, select, boolean } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

import CreditCard from '../src/CreditCard.js';
<Meta title="Design System|CreditCard" component={CreditCard} />


# Credit card

- This component must use `inputmode="numeric"` in order to bring up the correct keyboard on mobile.
```

config.js file:

```
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';

// automatically import all files ending in *.stories.js
configure(require.context('../stories', true, /\.stories\.(js|mdx)$/), module);
```

addons.js file:

```
import '@storybook/addon-actions/register';
import '@storybook/addon-links/register';
import '@storybook/addon-docs/register';
import '@storybook/addon-knobs/register';
```

presets.js file:

```
module.exports = ['@storybook/addon-docs/react/preset'];
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem was apparently [caused by whitespace](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/8675#issuecomment-592533923):

> A bit more detail: The direct cause is there is no empty line between the imports and the `<Meta />` component

Comment: A bit more detail: 
The direct cause is there is no empty line between the imports and the `<Meta />` component

Answer (score 0):

`Unexpected default export without title` can also happen if you do `export default function` inside of your story if for some reason want to reuse the story is better to simply export it without doing it with the `default` option

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it via add `title` as sample code

```
export default{
    title: 'Components/Button',

    BUTTON: {
        children: [`Button`]
    },
    ......
```